# If a generations ship was destroyed while in low Eath orbit (LEO), would debris fall to the surface?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, space-debris

I understand there are a lot of factors to consider here, but would it be possible for material from the ship's destruction to fall to earth and cause significant damage to a city? What is a reasonable amount of time to pass for the debris from the destruction to hit the Earth's surface?

It is relevant that the ship was built by humans and in the far future, but the material, size, and manner of destruction are irrelevant as long as it is possible for debris from its destruction to hit Earth. Basically I need to know if it is possible for the ship to be destroyed in some way and in a fairly tight time frame (minutes to days, not months to years) have debris hit the Earth's surface.

Material, Size, manner of destruction, as well as orbital altitude can all be modified to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: How big is this generation ship? What is it made out of? How was it destroyed? Big explosion?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! If you "understand there are a lot of factors to consider", then please help us narrow them down, otherwise the question may be closed for being too broad. As well as AngelPray's questions, what's the approximate orbital altitude of this ship?

Comment: @JC1138 please edit your question rather than clarifying in a comment. Comments have a tendency to get overlooked. And yes, the question needs clarifying, but once that was done, it will be a very nice question

Comment: It can be destroyed in many different ways, each of which can provide "debris" to your own specification. If you want a large city leveling impact then the ship can be left largely intact. If you want a city leveled and lots of minor impacts, that can happen too, if you want crap of various sizes floating about for decades and randomly raining destruction, then yes, you can have that too. And in fact, if you want all three, yes, you can have that too :) So tell us what you want and we'll blow that sucker up!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it isn't about worldbuilding.  If I remember my history correctly, the answer can be found by reading the history of the Skylab orbital platform.

Answer (score 7):

Let us consider what happened when a large man-made orbiter did fall to earth.

http://www.history.com/news/the-day-skylab-crashed-to-earth-facts-about-the-first-u-s-space-stations-re-entry

> On July 11, 1979, with Skylab rapidly descending from orbit, engineers
> fired the station’s booster rockets, sending it into a tumble they
> hoped would bring it down in the Indian Ocean. They were close. While
> large chunks did go into the ocean, parts of the space station also
> littered populated areas of western Australia. Fortunately, no one was
> injured....
>
> Mocking NASA’s inability to say precisely where Skylab would land, entrepreneurs across the country sold T-shirts emblazoned with large bullseyes. Another enterprising individual took a different tack and sold cans of “Skylab repellent.”  Few people felt reassured by NASA’s statement that the risk of human injury from the event was just “one in 152.”

A lot of Skylab pieces showered Australia.  Some are collected in a museum there.  Here is the biggest piece: an oxygen tank weighing about a ton.

from https://www.space.com/21122-skylab-space-station-remains-museum.html
[image: skylab oxygen tank]

So: if little Skylab can shower the earth with 1 ton pieces, your huge ship could definitely do the same.

A caveat as regards destruction: Having a big wad of metal fall on you will mush you, but your falling ship will not wreak dinosaur-killer scale havoc. Pieces falling out of orbit [are moving at approximately 270 miles per hour](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2011/09/the-strange-tale-of-the-skylabs-fall-from-orbit/245332/) when they hit: that is terminal velocity and will be true regardless of the mass of the falling piece,  That is true also for meteorites less than 10 tons which slow down in the atmosphere then fall at terminal velocity.

Big 10 ton+ meterorites have too much kinetic energy to slow all the way down.  They can hit at speeds of 5000 miles per hour or (much) more.  F = mv^2 and so these things are what make the huge craters.
https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/faqf/#12

Comment: 10 tons doesn't sound like a very heavy generation ship. In fact, I'd wager a guess it's a pretty draconian weight limit. In fact, ISS already overshoots the limit. Forty times over. And it's not a generation ship. It's a research lab with facilities for six people.

Comment: @John Dvorak: The 10 ton limit applies to meteorites incoming at enormous speeds.  They are not massive enough to retain that speed and the atmosphere brakes them.  10+ ton asteroids do retain their speed.  Any size thing in orbit is by definition not moving at tremendous speed or it would leave orbit.  The huge generation ship would hit hard if it came down at great speed but it is in orbit and so does not have great speed to come down with - it will fall at terminal velocity, only as fast as Skylab.

Comment: @Will An object in LEO orbit moves about 7.5 km/s (it changes with altitude). That's about 16875 miles per hour. Skylab slowed down to 270mph because it fell in a very flat orbit, which actually had it making a lot of orbits around the Earth while being slowed by atmospherical drag before it was effectively captured. An explosion could place parts of the spaceship in a highly elliptical orbit with a trajectory that would hit the Earth without time enough for any kind of braking to happen. There's no garantee that everything that falls from orbit does it at terminal speed.

Comment: @JohnDvorak, the OP said that the situation was caused by the ship exploding.  The pieces will be much smaller than the ship and likely not be compact or aerodynamic.

Comment: @Rekesoft Meteorites which end up falling at terminal velocity, 270 mph, enter the atmosphere at much higher speeds, 11 to 72 km/s. So orbital velocity, fast as it is, isn't actually that fast.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Meteorites which enter the atmosphere at more than 12 km/s don't hit the soil at 270mph. Either they never do, because they completely burn out mid-flight, or they impact at several kilometers per second. In any case, most meteorites are nothing but dust and ice, and so they disintegrate as they heat, thus losing nearly all of its kinetical energy. That's why the atmosphere is so good at slowing them down. A solid piece of metal is not going to be braked that much.

Comment: @Rekesoft Uh, no. Chelyabinsk. Entry speed about 18 km/s. Several fragments of it have been found, having fallen at terminal velocity. The Cape York and associated iron meteorites fell at terminal velocity (no significant crater other than what you'd expect from something falling at terminal velocity), as did Hoba. In the Sikhote-Alin fall (iron), which was witnessed, entry speed was estimated at 14 km/s, several fragments did land at higher speed, but certainly _not_ "several kilometers per second".

Comment: @KeithMorrison Most of the meteorites you mention were nothing but tiny fragments, easily slowed down. Chelyabinsk was falling significatively faster than terminal velocity when it exploded in the air. Some tiny fragments then fell down at terminal velocity. The Campo del Cielo meterorite was an iron meterorite just like the Cape York one, and would have flatten a city the size of New York. The Hoba meteorite was larger, and it is supposed to have glided gently over the Earth atmosphere thanks to its flat profile, like a pebble hoping against water. You can't be that lucky always.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, the answer is "Yes, that can happen." However, there are so many ways that it could happen that the full scope of "how" would be too broad.

Since you don't need the full scope, but rather need only a few good ideas, I will offer some.

1. During an explosion, pieces are going to be generally accelerated in all directions. If the explosion is strong enough, you can decide that sufficient acceleration has occurred on the debris to make it go in whatever direction you want.
2. During the explosion, perhaps one of the rockets was actively thrusting at that moment, or maybe it is thrusting in reaction to the explosion to help stabilize; either way, that rocket, and any arbitrarily large chunk(s) of the ship attached to it, break away because of the reduced structural integrity. This piece(s) could now be essentially a missile and could happen to randomly land wherever you want. This might be your best bet.
3. You said "in low earth orbit," but is it actually *orbiting* at that height? Similar to the answer from @AndreiROM if this is a new ship, or not new but is currently being moved from planet-to-orbit or orbit-to-planet, and it is being hauled up or down on a space elevator then all you need is for an accident where the elevator breaks or the ship breaks off it or similar. This would allow the entire structure to fall almost straight down if it's only at LEO altitude. A little bit more altitude and you could have it fall in an arc away from the elevator location. This would probably be the fastest option and would provide you with whatever time frame you wanted depending on the altitude the accident happened at: minutes, hours, days, even months or years... whatever you want, just change the altitude accordingly.

Of course, you can combine multiple ideas together. Perhaps a large shower of debris over a large area and a rocketing piece or two to specific locations.

Answer (score 3):

Unless it has additional force added, anything in LEO will eventually fall back to earth. There is enough atmospheric drag to cause it to slow down.

For a really good description of Low Earth Orbit, see [What’s So Special About Low Earth Orbit?](https://www.wired.com/2015/09/whats-special-low-earth-orbit/)

The question is, where and when will it eventually fall?

See [this](https://www.space.com/37370-cubesat-deorbit-space-junk-experiment.html) for a discussion on de-orbiting time frames.

If you want it AIMED at a city, then the applied force to de-orbit it would have to be precisely calculated and methodically applied. It would have to be a controlled reentry. And even then, it would not be a sure thing. However, the time frame could be in hours, if enough thrust were applied to slow it sufficiently. The orbit would effectively be changed from that of an orbiting object to that of a ballistic object - that is, a parabola, as if it were shot like an ICBM from earth. Their targeting can be very precise, but the applied maneuvering thrusts are very carefully controlled.

In point of fact, when vehicles are returning from the ISS, they are sometimes deliberately placed into a steep parabolic ballistic trajectory from their orbital trajectory. See this [very technical description](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19670019592.pdf), complete with graphs, from NASA, for re-entry trajectories. See particularly figure 2 for a 'Skipping reentry trajectory' - basically, puting it into a parabolic trajectory.

However, if you wanted it to accidentally hit a city, then introduce fate into your story. It is highly unpredictable as to where something will fall. The upper atmosphere is highly unpredictable. But the steeper the descent (the more velocity it looses) the quicker and more predictable the impact point. The more like a ballistic (parabolic) trajectory and less like an orbiting (circular) trajectory. The time frame can be anything from a week to decades, depending on the initial orbit and how much atmospheric drag it comes under.

As for the damage it would cause, it also depends on the impact trajectory and angle of approach. However, if it started from a stable low earth orbit, it would not have gained enough energy to be anything greater than a very big accidental localized collision.  It would be similar to a similar sized airplane falling to the ground. It might take out several city blocks, and even leave a trail of destruction if the angle of impact were really shallow, but it would not be a city-buster.

***TL;DR***

Think of the impact damage of the planes that hit the World Trade Center. They hit under full throttle, and the towers survived initial impact. Scale up the size of the aircraft to match the size of your generation ship, and you have some idea of the scale of the collision. The speed of the falling space ship would actually be somewhat less than the speed of these planes, since the ship would be under free fall, and the planes were under powered flight. And given that generational ships would probably not be aerodynamically shaped, atmospheric drag would be significantly greater than a plane.

Comment: Just as another comparison, the planes that hit the WTC were going significantly faster (nearly twice as fast) as an object that's reached terminal velocity.

Answer (score 1):

A generation ship is, by its very nature, going to be very big.

Assuming that its structure was largely complete, yes, it would most likely fall to the ground in a giant heap of twisted metal which would cause terrible destruction and devastation.

Of course the manner of its destruction is also very important. If it gets blown into a million pieces its impact on the ground is going to be much smaller, with only a few pieces being large enough to do any real damage (the debris would, however, cause untold chaos in our orbit, perhaps taking out every satellite we have).

If, however, the shipyard somehow lost control of the behemoth while towing it to a new location, for example, and it somehow "slipped" into Earths atmosphere, it would impact the ground like nothing that has ever hit the Earth before.

Depending on the size, it could be capable of causing, if not an extinction level event, at least global devastation (tsunamis, earthquakes, massive fires, not to mention nuclear fuel spills, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any estimate of the time between the moment of destruction and when debris would start colliding with earth and causing said destruction?

Comment: @JC1138 - depends on a lot of variables. A few hours, most likely. You can mostly make this stuff up. The thing to realize is that even if you see the disaster coming, there's very little authorities can do to stop it beyond predict where it's going to hit. Short of launching a nuclear strike and attempting to intercept it in high orbit, nothing it going to stop that thing. Even then, it would simply rain down in smaller, radioactive pieces, setting cities, and forests on fire, not to mention some large chunks which would cause craters the size of small towns.

Comment: @AndreiROM Don't forget the EMP of a high altitude nuclear burst.  All electronics in line of sight are going to be ruined.   That said, it wouldn't be a complete rain of the entire ship... parts will likely stay in orbit for some time.  Orbiting speeds are about 17,500 mph and the shuttle going at that speed would take about 8 minutes from atmospheric entry to landing, though that was a controlled descent.  The friction and heat would cause the pieces to sheer off the large debris and that which lands will be much smaller on entry.

Comment: @hszmv - I think all this will largely depend on the angle and speed with which it impacts the atmosphere, and whether the ship was even designed for atmospheric entry.

Comment: @AndreiROM, a generation ship may be big but by definition a very large part of it is going to be empty space, which means low density and higher likelihood of aerodynamic stress ripping it apart and scattering it as small debris.

Comment: @keithmorrison - I considered that, however it doesn't seem to be what the OP is interested in, and at the end of the day it's all just make believe anyway.

Comment: @AndreiROM, The Chixulub impactor is assumed to have been a comet between about 10 km across, with a density of 1650 kg/cubic meter, mass 5.23E+11 kg at roughly 50 km/s. To have similar kinetic energy from LEO (7 km/s), you need a mass of 2.67E+13 kg. Assuming the colony ship is built to roughly the same structural strength as a Stanford Torus, you get a density of about 0.13 kg/cubic meter, and a volume of 2.05E+14 cubic meters, or a cylinder (spun for gravity) 4 km across that's 16,313 km long.  Wait, maybe make the ship 8 km across? Well, now it's only 4,000 km long. So yeah...ELE unlikely.